# How to determine if date exists in an array list using joda time

Tags: java, arraylist, jodatime

Hello I am looking for a better way to determine existence of a date in a list of dates in Java using JodaTime. Currently this is what I am using:

```
private static void dateSearch() {
    ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>(); 
    dates.add(formatDate("2016-08-18T05:18:24"));
    dates.add(formatDate("2016-08-17T05:18:24"));
    dates.add(formatDate("2016-08-19T17:00:24"));
    Collections.sort(dates);
    Date today=new Date();
    int index=Collections.binarySearch(dates,today,new DateComparator());
    if(index>=0){
        System.out.println("Todays date was found " + index);
    }
}

//Here is the formatDate Function that produces date objects from strings
private static Date formatDate(String dateString) {    
    String format="yyyy-MM-dd";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString);
    String dateCreated = dateTime.toString(format);
    Date date = dateTime.toDate();
    return date;
}

//Here is the comparator I am using for the binary search 
private static class DateComparator implements Comparator<Date> {
    private String format="yyyy-MM-dd";

    @Override
    public int compare(Date d1,Date d2){    
        LocalDateTime dt1 = new LocalDateTime(d1);
        LocalDateTime dt2 = new LocalDateTime(d2);    
        return dt1.toString(this.format).compareTo(dt2.toString(this.format));
    }
}
```

What I'm using works but Im afraid it might take up a lot of resources and time as well when comparing a large list of dates. Is there an inbuilt way to do this with JodaTime?
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you converting the `Date`s to `LocaDateTime` in the comparator? `Date` also already implements `Comparable`, and why even use JodaTime if you're still going to use `Date`?

Comment: Shouldn't you sort the list with the same comparator you're using for the search?

Comment: Just an idea, why not use a HashMap?

Comment: @bradimus Thank you fort the feedback.You are right.It was a mistake.    .

Comment: @venktavb I prefer to use List for this current situation.My main purpose was to find a way of using JodaTime to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be reduced to:

```
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-08-18T05:18:24").toLocalDate());
dates.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-08-17T05:18:24").toLocalDate());
dates.add(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-08-19T17:00:24").toLocalDate());

System.out.println(dates.stream().anyMatch(LocalDate.now()::equals));
```

Which actually uses the JodaTime `LocalDate` instead of `java.util.Date`.

It does not print the index, but, as you said, you only want to check for existence.

Comment: @TAsk Oh, that might be more readable. I thought that that factory method was a for `java.time` thing.

Comment: Isn't the double colon a Java 8 construct? He wouldn't be using JodaTime with Java 8 because the classes were baked into the language.

Comment: Thank you @Jorn. This is what I was looking for.I went to great lengths to achieve something that could be done easily with Stream.

Comment: @LAROmega It was not said explicitly, so I tried this first.

Comment: The only problem here is that the current date will be determined by implicitly assigning the JVM’s current default time zone. That default varies, even *during* runtime! Time zone is crucial in determining a date because for any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone. Better to be explicit about the desired/expected time zone by passing a [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) object.

Comment: I was going to write a for loop for it. Then I stumbled upon your elegant solution. Great use of `stream` and `anymatch`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a list has time complexity `O(n log n)`. If you just want to know if the date exists, than apply the transformation that is done in `DateComparator` to every date in the list and the date you want to find in the list. Then just use `List.contains` to determine whether the element is contained. This has complexity `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you but I wanted a customised date search with customised formats that's why I went for that.